# How can I provide a single double and not a double vector in my code

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have some code that utilizes pmap_dbl to calculate some splits.  I have created an unweighted version and a weighted version. The unweighted version runs as expected and produces the desired output.

The weighted version utilizes my getRwt function (recency weight) and attempts to apply the calculated weight to split calculation.  This version is throwing the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `splt_1a`. x Result 1 must be a single double, not a double vector of length 4 i Input `splt_1a` is `pmap_dbl(...)`.
```

I believe this error is telling me instead of providing my function an individual race_date I'm providing a race_date column.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to provide the individual date. The race_date the function is looking fore is the race date of the current row.

Here is a reprex of my tibble, function and code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

df <- tibble(name=c("Bill","Bill","Bill","Bill"), n=c(1,2,3,4), trk=c("GP","GP","SA","GP"), TE=c(2,4,0,1), race_date=c("11/1/2020", "12/31/2020","2/28/2021","4/7/2021"))

df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   name      n trk      TE race_date 
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>     
#> 1 Bill      1 GP        2 11/1/2020 
#> 2 Bill      2 GP        4 12/31/2020
#> 3 Bill      3 SA        0 2/28/2021 
#> 4 Bill      4 GP        1 4/7/2021

getRwt <- function(a, b){
  interval <- interval(a, b)
  d <- round(time_length(interval, "day"))
  t <- if_else(d < 366,d/7, d/5) /290
  rwt <- exp(1)^-t
  return(rwt)
}

# Unweighted Version

df %>% 
  mutate(splt_1 = pmap_dbl(list(trk, n),  ~ sum(if_else(trk == ..1 & ..2 > n, TE, as.numeric(0))))) 
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   name      n trk      TE race_date  splt_1
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 Bill      1 GP        2 11/1/2020       0
#> 2 Bill      2 GP        4 12/31/2020      2
#> 3 Bill      3 SA        0 2/28/2021       0
#> 4 Bill      4 GP        1 4/7/2021        6

# Recency Weighted Version

df %>% 
  mutate(splt_1a = pmap_dbl(list(trk, n, race_date),  ~ sum(if_else(trk == ..1 & ..2 > n, TE, as.numeric(0))) * getRwt(race_date, ..3)))

#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `splt_1a`.
#> x Result 1 must be a single double, not a double vector of length 4
#> i Input `splt_1a` is `pmap_dbl(...)`.
```

*Created on 2021-04-14 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)*

Comment: What should be the arguments in your `getRwt` function? Because you passed the whole `race_date` column and the corresponding value of that column in each row in it.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR the getRwt function is looking for the race_date of the current row and the race_date that purrr passes in with the ...3.  I believe the second variable is working correctly, but not the first.

Comment: `..3` is actually the race_date of the current row. But the first argument is the whole race_date column. I think the error is there. But I still don't understand the difference between the arguments that you have in mind.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR my code is essentially calculating a conditional cumsum. That exactly what the unweighted version does successfully.  The weighted version is trying to apply a recency weight - so assume it process row 2 the getRwt function should use the race_date from row 1 and row 2 to calculate the recency weight, but instead of pass two dates I'm passing 1 date and a column.

Comment: It produces 4 `NA`s have you checked it before using it into `pmap`? It would be great if you just create an output of it and add it to your question. In that case I may be able to help you.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR  Yes, standalone getRwt works as expected. So you were able to get the code to work without the error - that progress.  Is it possible you passed the same date for the first and second values.

Comment: I used `pmap_dfc` instead of  `pmap_dbl` as it does not produce a single double.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I just got the same result as you. This is a tough one.  I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Are the outputs correct?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR  I was not anticipating the output being four new columns.  I was expecting 1.  The column with the ...1 appears to be the correct column.

Comment: I updated my code.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR  The unweighted version has just one column.  Column 1a is 0, 2, 0, 6. So the 0, 1.94, 0, 5.55 appears to be the correct weighted column, but why do we get the other three columns.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR using the same inputs is the equivalent of having an unweighted because we are saying the events happened the same day. As you can see This answer matches the unweighted result perfectly.  I wonder if the weighted terms has to be inside of the sum function - TE * getRwt(race_date, ..3) instead of outside.

Comment: Yes exactly that might be the case.

Comment: You were right! Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem solved thanks to a great collaboration**

You have to change the column type of `race_date` to `Date`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(race_date = mdy(race_date), 
         splt_1a = pmap_dbl(list(trk, n, race_date),  ~ sum(if_else(trk == ..1 & ..2 > n, TE * getRwt(race_date, ..3), as.numeric(0))))) %>%
  unnest_wider(splt_1a) 

# A tibble: 4 x 6
  name      n trk      TE race_date   ...1
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
1 Bill      1 GP        2 2020-11-01  0   
2 Bill      2 GP        4 2020-12-31  1.94
3 Bill      3 SA        0 2021-02-28  0   
4 Bill      4 GP        1 2021-04-07  5.66
```